# Is there a way to convert a column to a timeseries object of 30 minute interval?

Tags: python, r, for-loop, time-series

I have a data frame `df` with three columns `group`, `phase` and `count`.

Firstly,  I want to convert `phase` column to a timeseries object of 30 minute interval. for example,  phase 0 -> 0 min, phase 2 -> 30 mins, phase 3 -> 60 mins.......

Secondly, I want to plot timeseries (count vs phase)  for each group (A, B and C) -probably use a for loop to plot all three figures

End goal: compare time-series of Group A vs Group B vs Group C

```
#df
group,phase, count 
A,0,3000
A,1,3315
A,2,3690
A,3,4002
A,4,4210
B,0, 2000
B,1,2100
B,2,2215
B,3,2303
B,4,2412
C,0,3001
C,1,3120
C,2,3225
C,3,3350
C,4,3459
```

Desired output

```
# in a time series format 
group,phase, count
A, 0, 3000
A, 30, 3315
A, 60, 3690
A, 90, 4002
A, 120, 4210
B, 0, 2000
B, 30, 2100
B, 60, 2215
B, 90, 2303
B, 120, 2412
C, 0, 3001
C, 30, 3120
C, 60, 3225
C, 90, 3350
C, 120, 3459
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `R` indexing for this.  Add 1 to the 'phase' (as `R` indexing starts from 1) and then pass the vector of values in the order of replacement

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(phase = c(0, 30, 60, 90, 120)[phase + 1])
```

-output

```
#    group phase count
#1      A     0  3000
#2      A    30  3315
#3      A    60  3690
#4      A    90  4002
#5      A   120  4210
#6      B     0  2000
#7      B    30  2100
#8      B    60  2215
#9      B    90  2303
#10     B   120  2412
#11     C     0  3001
#12     C    30  3120
#13     C    60  3225
#14     C    90  3350
#15     C   120  3459
```

---

Or another option is `seq`

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(phase = seq(0, length.out = n(), by = 30))
```

---

or in `base R`

```
df1$phase <- c(0, 30, 60, 90, 120)[df1$phase + 1]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), phase = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), count = c(3000L, 
3315L, 3690L, 4002L, 4210L, 2000L, 2100L, 2215L, 2303L, 2412L, 
3001L, 3120L, 3225L, 3350L, 3459L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```